# How to change my user account on git?

Tags: git, github

I changed my **username** and my **email** and I would like to change my **username_old** to username_new but I have always this git error.

$ git push

remote: Permission to k***/minetest.git denied to username_old.

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/k***/minetest.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

I tried this link: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/

When I ask about my username it show **username_new**

I think that I must to delete a certificate on Windows 10 but I dont know where is this file?

I have the same error but in windows 10  : 
https://superuser.com/questions/1064197/how-to-switch-git-user-at-terminal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove credentials from git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is already answered in this question:

[remove credentials from git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git)

"Open User Accounts by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking User Accounts and Family Safety (or clicking User Accounts, if you are connected to a network domain), and then clicking User Accounts. In the left pane, click Manage your credentials."

There you can delete the info and execute the git command again with a user/command prompt.

Comment: if answer is already available , then you shouldn't answer it and mark question as duplicate, otherwise unnecessary you might get downvote on your answer.

Comment: But the answer/question is hard to find !

Comment: I just flagged it - sorry I wasn't aware of the possibility until now.